# Padding ssis input source columns to avoid truncation errors?

Tags: sql, ssis

First post. In SSIS I am using an ODBC Source, and the database (or ODBC driver) doesn't appear to report column metadata correctly for any of the tables in the database for varchar type columns. Therefore, each time I import a table, I get truncation errors on all the varchar fields. Is there any way to set the size of these fields besides doing it ONE AT A TIME in the advanced editor? When importing a flat file source it lets you select a padding % for string fields. Does something like this exist for OLE or ODBC sources? If not, is there any way I can override the column length to, say, force them all to be VARCHAR(1000)?

Comment: "ONE AT A TIME in the advanced editor" is the only way I know.

Comment: Thanks! From hours of investigation, that appears to be the only thing I can find as well short of using a SQL command on the ODBC source (instead of TABLE) and then CASTING all the varchar columns to some large number. But that requires just as much manual intervention pretty much on each table I import.

Answer (score 0):

I have never experience SQL Server providing the wrong meta data for an ODBC connection and it is unlikely you have a ghost in the machine (Deus Ex Machina). The meta data of the column can be set in the ODBC source via the advanced editor. I am willing to bet that is where the difference is. To confirm this:

1. Right click the ODBC connection and select the Advanced Editor
2. Click on the Input/Ouput Properties tab
3. Expand OLE DB Source Output
4. Expand both External Columns and Output Columns
5. Inspect each column pair and verify that the meta data matches
6. Correct any outages in the meta data

Let me know if that works. If it does not work, please provide data and SQL query you are using.

Comment: Input and Output columns are all set the same and based on what the ODBC connection reports. The problem isn't SQL server or SSIS. The problem is the Cache database reports that a varchar column is defined as, say, VARCHAR(20), but when you review the actual data, there are strings/data in the column that are more than 20 chars. These are what SSIS is truncating/choking on. Hence, the only way I can come up with to work around this is to PAD the VARCHAR columns (or set them all to a large number like VARCHAR(5000). My goal was to not have to do this for 500 columns individually in adv editor.

Comment: @adveach I posted a new answer due to length.

Answer (score 0):

The VARCHAR field width must be set to the maximum incoming field width. I know the default field width is 50. Regardless, each field must be set. I previously worked on a project with large numbers of columns on the input files. My solution was to store the meta-data for the columns in a database table and then I built a C# application to read in the meta-data and then modify the *.dtsx file and set the meta data on all columns. This is the best solution that I am aware of to automate the task.

Unfortunately, I don't have much experience with pulling data through ODBC. Are you pulling from an Access database? Or, what are you pulling from?